# Woo REST API v3 - Getting JSON ERROR: Syntax error - Code: 500 on updates orders

Tags: json, rest, woocommerce, syntax

I use the Woo REST API v3 from WooCommerce and will update some orders from "pending" to "completed".

Since couple of days i cant use this method, because i get an error message:

```
    [response:Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClientException:private] => Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\Response Object
        (
            [code:Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\Response:private] => 500
            [headers:Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\Response:private] => Array
                (
                    [Date] => Fri, 03 May 2019 13:38:40 GMT
                    [Server] => Apache
                    [X-Robots-Tag] => noindex
                    [Link] => ; rel="https://api.w.org/"
                    [X-Content-Type-Options] => nosniff
                    [Access-Control-Expose-Headers] => X-WP-Total, X-WP-TotalPages
                    [Access-Control-Allow-Headers] => Authorization, Content-Type
                    [Expires] => Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
                    [Cache-Control] => no-transform, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
                    [Set-Cookie] => wfwaf-authcookie-19507c40e0a99b44e590377ed6e2e841=1%7Cadministrator%7C661afdd670ad0705856715deeede671d9a78039a07457b4cf523451dd5158496; expires=Sat, 04-May-2019 01:38:41 GMT; Max-Age=43200; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
                    [Strict-Transport-Security] => max-age=31556926
                    [Content-Length] => 0
                    [Connection] => close
                    [Content-Type] => application/json; charset=UTF-8
                )

            [body:Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\Response:private] =>
```

and

```
[message:protected] => JSON ERROR: Syntax error
    [string:Exception:private] => 
    [code:protected] => 500
    [file:protected] => /var/www/xxx/html/api/vendor/automattic/woocommerce/src/WooCommerce/HttpClient/HttpClient.php
    [line:protected] => 378
```

JSON ERROR: Syntax error
Code: 500
Body:

Everything other methods like get or post will work without JSON Error. I didn't have edit my products.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your woocommerce object initialization:

```
'query_string_auth' => true,
'verify_ssl' => false
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by fixing an notice generated by the wordpress for a depreciated function. Try to see the error log and fix all the notices / warnings.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with PUT method, I changed them to POST and everything now works fine